# Modify a totals row in a table for specific row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was able to create a totals row for a table without any issues.
But, there is a column (column number 7) of which I don't want to calculate the total, but instead show the value of a cell from the previous month to the current one.
Here it is an image (I had to use an image because this table this table is dynamically generated pulling data from a SharePoint list) of the table:

[image]

As you can see I have a **Month** column and a **Pending** column.
We are in June, so I would like the Pending column to show "**4**".
This is what I've done so far:

JS:

```
var theDate = new Date();
var prevMonth = theDate.getMonth() - 1;
prevMonth = prevMonth === -1 ? 12 : prevMonth;
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";
rows = [];
$('#myTable tr td:nth-child(7)').each(function ()
{
    var rowText = $(this).text();
    rows.push(rowText);
    var n = month[prevMonth];

    if (rowText !== n)
    {
        $('#myTable tr:last td:nth-child(7)').text($(this).text());
    }
});
```

I can't figure out how to read the values of each row in both columns at the same time.

Comment: In the 'totals' row for the 'Pending' column, you want to show whatever value is in the 'Pending' column for the current month, correct?

Comment: I would like to show the previous month's value. That's why this part: `var prevMonth = theDate.getMonth() - 1;`. So, the value should be May's value (4). Thanks!

Comment: you pending formula is actually pending(n) = notices_received(n) - decline_participation(n) + pending(n-1). Can you make the change to se t the value accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the row containing the previous month's name. If you've found that you can get the value of the **Pending** column for that month and place it in the **Totals** row.

**JS**

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var today = new Date();
var thisMonth = today.getMonth(); 
var prevMonth = thisMonth == 0 ? 11 : thisMonth - 1;
var month = months[prevMonth];

var val = $("#myTable tr:contains('" + month + "') td:nth-of-type(7)").text();
$("#myTable tr:last-of-type td:nth-of-type(7)").text(val);
```

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fFs6k/3/)** for a working example.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. It looks like I didn't explain my question correctly. The rest of the columns are just fine, they get their values using a totally different piece of code which work perfectly. At this moment I only care about the Pending column. For example. We are in June: the cell below the Pending column (total row) should show a 4. Next month whenever the data in updated, that cell will show whatever is entered for the month of June. In conclusion, this cell will always need to be a month behind.

Comment: @cubanGuy I've edited my answer to reflect your wishes.